# Using ASCIIMath, how can we align variables in proper order in a system of linear equations

Tags: mathjax, asciimath

For instance how can we display folliwing in MathJax using ASCIIMath:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as close as I could come:

```
{
  [      -x_1, ,   , ,   ,+,x_4,=,\qquad 130],
  [          , ,   , ,x_3,-,x_4,=,\qquad\quad 60],
  [          , ,x_2,-,x_3, ,   ,=,-240],
  [\qquad x_1,-,x_2, ,   , ,   ,=,\qquad\quad 50]
:}
```

The spacing is a bit *ad hoc*, but perhaps it is good enough for you.